# On the (strong) convexity of a function. Why does it stop to be strongly convex?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let $f\colon\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ be given as follows
$$
f(\mathbf{w})=\frac{\lambda}{2}\lVert\mathbf{w}\rVert^2+\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{w};\mathbf{x}_i),
$$
where the so-called loss function $\mathcal{L}$ is given by the "hinge-loss"
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{w};\mathbf{x}_i)=\max\big(0, 1-y_i(\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}_i)\big)=1-y_i\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}_i,\quad y_i\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}_i<1,
$$
where $y_i\in\{\pm1\}$.

$f$ can be shown to be $\lambda$-strongly convex over $\Bbb{R}^n$. However, in [this paper](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~nati/Publications/PegasosMPB.pdf), Shalev-Shwartz et al. state that if we further incorporate a bias term $b$ in $\mathcal{L}\colon\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, i.e.,
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{w},b;\mathbf{x}_i)=\max\big(0, 1-y_i(\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}_i+b)\big)=1-y_i(\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}_i+b),\quad y_i(\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}_i+b)<1,
$$
then $f$ ceases to be strongly convex, since $\mathbf{f}$ **becomes piece-wise linear in the direction of** $\mathbf{b}$.

Could you please confirm or contradict this fact and elaborate more on why this happens? What do the bold-faced words above really mean?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The new objective function is indeed strongly convex in $w$ (because of the $\frac{1}{2}\|w\|^2$ term) but not in the augmented variable $(w, b)$. To see this, consider the hyperplane $w = 0$.

Comment: That's correct. I have figured out what is going on here. Thanks for your comment @dohmatob! By the way, could you explain to me the bold-faced phrase?