# What makes this function no longer strongly convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given as $$ f(\mathbf{w}, b)=\frac{\lambda}{2}\lVert\mathbf{w}\rVert^2+\sum_{i=1}^{k}\max\big(0, 1-y_i(\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}_i + b)\big)$$

In this question: [On the (strong) convexity of a function. Why does it stop to be strongly convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579009/on-the-strong-convexity-of-a-function-why-does-it-stop-to-be-strongly-convex) the function is claimed to not be strongly convex. However, I believe it is strongly convex. The function $\frac \lambda 2||w||^2$ is strongly convex, and $\max(0, 1 - y_i(w^Tx_i + b))$ is convex, since it is a maximum of two affine functions (the second is an affine function of $w$ and $b$). The sum of convex functions is convex, and a convex function plus a strongly convex function is strongly convex.

So what makes $f$ not strongly convex?

Comment: It is not strongly convex in the variable $b$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ were strongly convex, then $f(0, \cdot)$ were strongly convex for $n = k = 1$ and $x = 0$ and $y = 1$. But this function is $\max(0, 1 - \cdot)$, which is piecewise linear and thus not strongly convex.